# Android: "Auto refresh" after a certain time

Tags: java, android, multithreading, runnable

i have search how i can do an "Auto refresh" or a runnable method for my program, i saw some posts about handlers and threads...
I think that what im search from is a thread but i cant get the program to work...
Let me show you some code:

```
refresh.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getUrlText();
            if (time.getText().toString().equals("")
                    || time.getText().toString().equals("0")) {
                mins = 0;
            } else {

                mins = Integer.parseInt(time.getText().toString());
                setTimer(mins);
                t.start();


            }

        }

        private void setTimer(int mins) {
            miliSecTime = mins * 60 * 1000;

        }
    });

    t= new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

            while (true) {
                long time = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
                int seconds = (int) (time / 1000);
                if (seconds > miliSecTime) {
                    getUrlText();
                    start = System.currentTimeMillis();

                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

So, this part of code should get a number from the user and then execute getUrlText(); every x minutes, where x is the number that user input...
My problem should be in the run but i can't figure out what is...
Thank you in advance for the help :)

Comment: For something like that, you'd be better off using http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.

Declare these in your Activity:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable timedTask = new Runnable(){

    @Override
    public void run() {
        getUrlText();
        handler.postDelayed(timedTask, 1000);
    }};
```

Then set your onClick:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getUrlText();
            handler.post(timedTask);
        }
    });
```

This will execute `timedTask` every 1000 milliseconds. Increase this number as necessary.

I'm not sure what you're doing with `mins` and so on but put all your logic that needs to be executed periodically into the `timedTask` `Runnable`. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 6):

You can use this code for implemented of Auto-Refresh of your activity for a certain times as below.

First you can use namespace of header as below.

```
import android.os.Handler;
```

After create new instance of `Handler`.

```
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
```

Then write a one method for refresh as below and call in `OnCreate` method scope, here i have used 5000 milliseconds or 5 seconds. You can change as your wish.

```
private void doTheAutoRefresh() {
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             // Write code for your refresh logic
            doTheAutoRefresh();
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

Final code for put method of auto refresh as below.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    doTheAutoRefresh();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**1. create Handler**

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
```

**2. Create Runnable object**

```
public final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // your code while refreshing activity
    }
};
```

**3. Call Method of Handler Object**

```
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 3000);
```

//3000  is time in milliseconds

// put this method in onCreate()

// onResume() or Where refreshing take place